# Kafka:why topic creation in kafka is done in zookeper host instead of broker

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to learn Kafka,
This is the command I saw for topic creation.

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partition 2 --topic test
```

1. why do we pass zookeeper host,port for topic creation, instead to broker(s) information?
2. what does zookeeper do with topic?
3. Does topic info is persisted in zookeeper

Answer (score 1):

Which Kafka version are you using? In the latest version, the `--zookeeper` parameter is deprecated and you can use the `--bootstrap-server` instead, providing Kafka broker(s) address(s).
Anyway, the topic information will be still stored in Zookeeper. This is the way how Kafka works.
The fact that `--zookeeper` is deprecated is because the development is going in the direction of making clients less aware of Zookeeper and doing all the operations connecting to the Kafka brokers; it's the broker doing the operation on Zookeeper then.